# In this X86 emulator, why is the overflow flag getting set when adding 0xFFFF to 0xFFFF?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, eflags, x86-emulation

I'm building an x86 emulator, and I'm using [this online x86 sandbox](https://yjdoc2.github.io/8086-emulator-web/compile) to check my work. In my emulator, running this code:

```
mov AX, 0xFFFF
add AX, AX
```

...sets AX to 0xFFFE and sets the overflow flag to 0.

In the sandbox, the same code sets the overflow flag to 1. This doesn't make sense to me, because every definition of the OF I've read explains that it gets set if 1) **the source and destination operands have the same sign**, and 2) **the sign of the result != the sign of the source/destination operands**.

Here, we're adding 0b1111 1111 1111 1111 to 0b1111 1111 1111 1111. The result is 0b1111 1111 1111 1110. The sign bit of the source, destination, and result are all 1. Whether we interpret this as 0xFFFF + 0xFFFF = 0xFFFE (implicitly 0x1FFFE), or as -1 + -1 = -2, the sign is not changing.

Is this sandbox implementation wrong? If not, can you help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: It's open source, https://github.com/YJDoc2/8086-Emulator-Web/, so if anyone's curious they could look for the bug in the emulator.  It's great that an open-source emulator with single-step debugging and a nice GUI exists, but if they got this very basic thing wrong, who knows what other bugs might exist?  I wouldn't trust it or recommend it for anyone to use until it passes some stress-tests try to check all the results of every instruction for many input values.  I've heard of such tests for various 8-bit ISAs, I assume they exist for 8086.

Comment: I checked with `pushf` / `pop dx` and `jo repeat`, and the wrong FLAGS value isn't just in the GUI.  `jo` is taken, and the `0x0800` bit in the popped value is set.  The emulator sets OF on `0x8000 + 0x8000` as well, but does finally clear is on `0 + 0` once all the bits are shifted out.  So IDK if they're setting OF = SF, or OF = CF since I didn't test other values.  Those flags are all separate for a reason.

Comment: As the others have said this is a bug in that online sandbox. You could use another online service as a sandbox. In particular https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/util/other/enhdebug/1.32b/  . Once loaded you can use DOS debug for simple testing. I haven't observed any known bugs with this particular emulator.

Comment: @Joshua: As Peter Cordes noted, it should be filed on https://github.com/YJDoc2/8086-Emulator/issues instead.  Join the party, I just filed two of my own :)

Comment: It of course doesn't handle some of the more esoteric undocumented features of the 8086 like using REP or REPNE to negate the product of IMUL/MUL and negate the quotient from an IDIV instruction. This came about because the Intel 8086 microcode used the flag that says there is a REP/REPNE prefix on an instruction as a temporary bit to store whether exactly one of the operands was negative.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I haven't checked but I somehow suspect that a modern x86 processor doesn't have that REP IMUL thing.

Comment: @Joshua That doesn't apply to a modern processor but if one is emulating an actual Intel 8086 for purposes of running antiquated software/games it might be a compatibility thing to look at, I don't know what kind of emulator the OP is wiring or what his objectives are.

Answer (score 5):

```
Z:\>debug
-a
0DAB:0100 MOV AX, FFFF
0DAB:0103 ADD AX, AX
0DAB:0105
-g 0105
AX=FFFE BX=0000 CX=0000 DX=0000 SP=FFFE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=0DAB ES=0DAB SS=0DAB IP=0105 NV UP EI NG NZ AC PO CY
```

You're right. Sandbox wrong.

I expected this before trying it because logically (-1 + -1 = -2) and no signed overflow occurred. V is signed overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The emulator is wrong, and the source code shows a totally wrong implementation, just setting OF with the same condition as CF.   Those flags are separate for a reason!  Also, they set SF any time CF is set, even if the top bit of the 16-bit result is zero.

It's open source, https://github.com/YJDoc2/8086-Emulator-Web is a front-end for the 8086-Emulator library written in Rust (compiled to wasm) by the same folks who wrote the front-end.

It's great that an open-source emulator with single-step debugging and a nice GUI exists, but if they got this very basic thing wrong, who knows what other bugs might exist? I wouldn't trust it or recommend it for anyone to use until it passes some stress-tests try to check all the results of every instruction for many input values. I've heard of such tests for various 8-bit ISAs, I assume they exist for 8086.

---

I had a look in their 8086-Emulator library, and luckily found the emulation code for `add` in the first file that seemed likely, [`src/lib/instructions/arithmetic.rs`](https://github.com/YJDoc2/8086-Emulator/blob/master/src/lib/instructions/arithmetic.rs#L578).

The code sets both CF and OF according to the same condition: zero-extend the inputs to 32-bit, add, then check for greater than 0xffff unsigned.  That should work for carry-out, but it'll fail to detect signed overflow in `0x7fff + anything`, as well as false-positive when adding two small negative numbers like you are.

```
pub fn word_add(vm: &mut VM, op1: u16, op2: u16) -> u16 {
    let res = op1 as u32 + op2 as u32;        // 32-bit sum of zero-extended inputs
    set_all_flags(
        vm,
        FlagsToSet {
            zero: res == 0,                      // correct
            overflow: res > u16::MAX as u32,     // BUG
            parity: has_even_parity(res as u8),  // correct, PF is set from the low 8
            sign: res >= 1 << 15,                // BUG
            carry: res > u16::MAX as u32,        // correct
            auxillary: ((op1 & 0xF) + (op2 & 0xF)) > 0xF, // correct, carry-out from the low nibble.  Typo for "auxilliary", though.
        },
    );
    res as u16
}
```

Rust has so many ways they could have gotten this correct, like `(a as i16).wrapping_add(b as i16) == a as i16 as i32 + b as i16 as i32`.  Or any other way of sign-extending both sides to 32-bit before adding to get the true value, then compare with a wrapped 16-bit add, or with the truncation of the true value back to 16-bit.

Or `(a as i16).checked_add(b)` and check that the result isn't `None`, or `(a as i16).overflowing_add(b)` to get separate `i16` and `bool` outputs.  (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i16.html#method.overflowing_add).  That i16 output can easily be used to get SF more simply as `signed_sum < 0`.

See also http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt re: more ways of understanding carry-out (unsigned overflow) vs. signed overflow in addition.  For addition, signed-overflow can only happen when both inputs have the same sign, and the result has the opposite sign.  Or an easy way that always works for add and subtract is to sign-extend the inputs and do a wider operation, and check that the full result can be narrowed back to 8 or 16-bit without changing the value.  (e.g. `res as i16 as i32` to redo sign-extension from 16-bit, to get a 32-bit value to compare against the full result.)

**The SF condition is wrong, too**.  They'd set SF on `0x8000 + 0x8000` which wraps back to zero, because they're comparing `0x10000u >= 0x8000u`.  They need to test just that bit, like `(res >> 15) & 1`, not any higher bits that might have carry-out.

---

Their hack of using wider arithmetic does make it easy for them to implement even `adc` with correct (I think) carry-flag handling, but the same wrong handling of OF.

(Emulating `adc` using only operations of the same width as the `adc` is quite hard, because the usual carry-out formula of `a+b < a` unsigned doesn't work for `a+b + CF < a`; adding 0xFFFFu + 1u to something is the same as adding zero, if you're using wrapping 16-bit addition, so you'd have to check each addition step separately.  Unless you have higher bits to hold that carry.  Or if you have language or hardware support, which Rust exposes with `carrying_add(self, rhs: i16, carry: bool) -> (i16, bool)` in a new API that's still only in the nightly builds.  That for `i64` would totally solve the problem.)

Comment: "who knows what other bugs might exist?" I found three more :) https://github.com/YJDoc2/8086-Emulator/issues

Comment: @NateEldredge: FLAGS handling in multiple other instructions is wrong too, unsurprisingly.  e.g. their `word_imul` sets OF and CF if the upper half isn't `0xFFFF`, rather than checking if `res == res as i16 as i32`.  So it thinks `1 * 1` overflows...  And `neg` looks way overcomplicated; in x86 it sets FLAGS the same as `sub` from `0`.  They do manage to get OF set correctly for `neg`, though, unlike `sub`.